# Where to call method

Tags: ios, objective-c, methods

I am developing an app with Xcode and I need some help.

I need to call a method in a spot so that it does not interfere with other code.

In my app I have a ball that moves randomly and I have score. The ball code is in the viewDidLoad method.

Now I need to add the score code. I have all of the code but I don't know where to put it.

If I put the code in the viewDidLoad, then every time that the score increases then the ball goes back to the starting position.

Now I need to find out where to put the code for the score. Any help would be great.

Comment: Why did you delete this question and then post a new one?

Comment: @Lover Do not misuse the website. You could have edited your question to improve it. That would've put it back at the top of the list. One big improvement is: show your code. How are we supposed to find out what's wrong with it if we can't see your code?

Comment: I found out the problem. I was using Autolayout which has to be disabled

Answer (score 1):

Add source code after creation of ball, by using NSTimer with repeat `YES` with specific timeInterVal.
suchlike

After creation of Ball code :

```
[NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.6f target:self selector:@selector(mySourceMethod) userInfo:nil repeats:YES]; /// here also you can change time interval of NSTimer;
```

And then put code of **mySourceMethod** such like

```
-(void)mySourceMethod
{
  // my code of mySourceMethod;
}
```

Comment: what do I put in mySourceMethod

Comment: @LoverofApple - your code of movement of ball

Comment: so where do I put the other ball code

Comment: @LoverofApple - what do you mean ?? i can not get ?

Comment: so you said to put the ball code inside mySourceMethod. But then what do I do with the other ball code???

Comment: how many balls you have ?

Comment: I have 1 ball in my game

Comment: so what do I do iPatel???

Comment: Then first create ball in viewDidLoad method  then call above method for only change position of ball. Here you need to do only changes  of position of the ball, (random position)

Comment: the ball code is working fine for me. But now I need to implement score without affecting the ball

Comment: sorry i can not got what you exact want :(

Comment: So as I stated in my question, I want to add score to my game but I don't know where to put the score code

Comment: Can u help me with this iPatel

Comment: I found out the problem. I was using Autolayout which has to be disabled